# How large must $\delta$ be to have certain probability?

Tags: probability

I've been reading Hopcroft's "Foundations of Data Science", specifically the part about probabilities, there's this exercise:  (12.16 If you wish to check it, the book is free).

Let $s$ be the sum of $n$ independent random variables $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ where for each i:

$x_i = \begin{cases} 0, \text{Prob } p \\ 1, \text{Prob } 1- p
\end{cases}$

The question is:

How large must $\delta$ be if we wish to have Prob($s<(1-\delta)m) < \epsilon$ ?

What I've done so far:

The book mentions a theorem (12.3) and it states:

For any $ \displaystyle \delta > 0$, Prob($s>(1+\delta)m) < \left(\frac{e^\delta}{(1+\delta)^{(1+\delta)}}\right)^m$

So far I know the expected value of the sum is $E[s] = n(1-p)=m$

I tried making $\epsilon$ equal to the right hand of the inequation of Theorem 12.3 but I get no results, what is the appropiate way to approach this problem?

Comment: I may be missing something, but I see two things. First, it seems like $m$ is a red herring. The question is basically “How small must $t$ be if you wish to have Prob$(s<t)<\epsilon$?” You have a theorem that says the probability that $s$ is *greater* than some value is smaller than something (messy), but it seems like you need a theorem (or to prove) that the probability that $s$ is *smaller* than some value is smaller than something ($\epsilon$). [I notice now that in the discussion preceding theorems 12.3 and 12.4 (more relevant), $m=np$ is stated. Perhaps this applies to the exercise.

Comment: Well, of course for this exercise the value of $m$ is not $np$ since the distribution is different, in this exercise $m=n(1-p).$

Comment: I guess that makes more sense. I’m not aware that the letter $m$ should automatically represent an expected value of some quantity under discussion when it’s not explicitly defined, but it does look like that makes the most sense here.

Comment: I supposed that too, I've read the page about 3 times and I can't grasp any hint yet.